# jquery datatables 1.10 dates sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, datatable

I know that there are many discussions related to sorting in jquery DataTables plugin, but I can't make it work.
So, I am using jquery DataTables 1.10 and I have a table that has one date column, that has to be sorted descending. The format of the date is 'dd-mm-yyyy'
I tried to use a plugin, but id didn'work..

Could someone come up with a ideea?

The code used is:

```
// Date (dd . mm[ . YYYY]) 
function calculate_date(date) {
    var date = date.replace(" ", "");

    if (date.indexOf('.') > 0) {
        /*date a, format dd.mn.(yyyy) ; (year is optional)*/
        var eu_date = date.split('.');
    } else {
        /*date a, format dd/mn/(yyyy) ; (year is optional)*/
        var eu_date = date.split('/');
    }

    /*year (optional)*/
    if (eu_date[2]) {
        var year = eu_date[2];
    } else {
        var year = 0;
    }

    /*month*/
    var month = eu_date[1];
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = 0+month;
    }

    /*day*/
    var day = eu_date[0];
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = 0+day;
    }

    return (year + month + day) * 1;
}

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['eu_date-asc'] = function(a, b) {
    x = calculate_date(a);
    y = calculate_date(b);

    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['eu_date-desc'] = function(a, b) {
    x = calculate_date(a);
    y = calculate_date(b);

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0));
};
```

But, since 1.10 datatables update, it does not work anymore

Edit:
The declaration of the table is:

```
dt_orders: function(){
    if($('#dt_orders').length) {

        var oTable;
        var id = 0;
        var responsiveHelper = undefined;
        var breakpointDefinition = {
            tablet: 1024,
            phone : 480
        };
        var oTable = $('#dt_orders');

        oTable = $('#dt_orders').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bSortable": true,
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
            "sAjaxSource": "view/orders/server_side.php",
            "autoWidth" : false,
            "fnPreDrawCallback": function () {
                // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
                if (!responsiveHelper) {
                    responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(oTable, breakpointDefinition);
                }
            },
            "fnDrawCallback" : function (oSettings) {
                responsiveHelper.respond();
            },                  
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                /* Add some extra data to the sender */
                aoData.push( { "name": "filter", "value": $('#filter').val()} );
                /*$.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                    fnCallback(json)
                } );*/
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType" : "json",
                    "type" : "POST",
                    "url" : sSource,
                    "data" : aoData,
                    "success" : fnCallback
                });                     
            },                                              
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData ) {
                responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
                var today   = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var parts   = aData[9].split("-");
                var d1      = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                test = ( d1 > today ) ? 0 : 1;
                if (aData[16] == 1) {
                    test = 2;
                }
                //alert(d1 + " >= " + today + " : " + test);
                switch(test){
                    case 2: /* livrate */
                        $('td', nRow).addClass('green');
                        break;
                    case 1: /* in trecut */
                        if ((aData[13] == 0)) { /* confirmate & neconfirmate -- nesterse*/
                            $('td', nRow).addClass('red');
                        }  else if (aData[16] == 1) { /* livrate */
                            $('td', nRow).addClass('green');
                        } else {
                            $('td', nRow).addClass('');
                        }
                        break;
                    case 0: /* in viitor */
                        if ((aData[13] == 0) && (aData[14] == 1)) { /* confirmate si nesterse*/
                            $('td', nRow).addClass('blue');
                        } else if ((aData[13] == 0) && (aData[14] == 0)) {
                            $('td', nRow).addClass('blue');
                        } else {
                            $('td', nRow).addClass('');
                        }
                        break;
                }
                //var hammertime = Hammer(document.getElementByName('td', nRow));
                //$('td', nRow).hammer().on("dragleft dblclick", function() {
                /*$('td', nRow).on("dragleft dblclick", function() {
                //hammertime.on("doubletap swipe dblclick", function() {
                    if (aData[13] == 0) {
                        window.location.href = "?route=home/orders/insert&id="+aData[14];
                    } else {
                        smoke.alert("Deleted orders cannot be edited!", function(e){
                        }, {
                            ok: "Ok",
                            cancel: "Nope",
                        });                             
                    }
                }); */              
            },                                      
            "bAutoWidth": true,             
            "aoColumns": [
                { sWidth: '3%', "bSortable": false },
                { sWidth: '8%' },
                { sWidth: '11%' },
                { sWidth: '8%' },
                { sWidth: '8%' },                       
                { sWidth: '10%' },
                { sWidth: '8%' },
                { sWidth: '10%' },
                { sWidth: '10%' },
                { sWidth: '6%', type: 'eu_date'},
                { sWidth: '10%' },
                { sWidth: '0%', "bVisible": false},
                { sWidth: '0%', "bVisible": false},
                { sWidth: '0%', "bVisible": false },
                { sWidth: '0%', "bVisible": false },
                { sWidth: '0%', "bVisible": false },
                { sWidth: '0%', "bVisible": false },
                { "sClass": "center", sWidth: '10%', "bSortable": false }
            ],              
            "aaSorting": [[9, 'asc']]
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you tried? Show to us some code

Comment: show to us the decleration of the datatable plz

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD: HI, I have updated the declaration of the datatable, could you help?

Comment: Did you make it work in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Since we speak about server side script, all the sorting should be done there, not in the jQuery script
So, take care of the order of the columns and also, order the sql query as you need it to be displayed